# Jenkins bypass web ui and trigger builds from shell

Tags: bash, jenkins

Is it possible to

```
start a Jenkins build
see its stdout/stderr progress
when it's done, run another bash script
```

all from the command line / terminal / shell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jenkins cli](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) specifically with build command